# Step progress bar ExtJs

Tags: extjs, progress-bar

How I can implement a step progress bar in ExtJs like this?: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create step progressbar with help `dataview`. And write simple interface for synchronize your component with this `dataview`

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33gc)