# How to implement progress indicator in ext js

Tags: extjs

[image]

I want to implement the above image in ext js. What functions we should use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Step progress bar ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149321/step-progress-bar-extjs)

Comment: Yes.. Thanks @pvlt